# Form submit with bootstrap and nodejs

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap

I am using boostrap (via MDB 4) and am trying to get the contact form to work. I have the form presenting as expected. It contains the following button outside the `</form>` tag

```
    <a class="btn btn-primary" onclick="document.getElementById('contact-form').submit();">Send</a>
```

The opening line of the form is:

```
    <form id="contact-form" name="contact-form" action="/contact" method="POST">
```

I am trying to understand how I get the form contents to nodejs and have the following in my Express routes

```
   app.post('/contact', function(req, res){
        console.log(req.body.name); 
        console.log(req.body.email);
        console.log(req.body.subject);
        console.log(req.body.message);
    // code to store here later
   });
```

I know this I am hitting this block as I can console out text from within the route but I get an error every time:

```
     TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

All the examples seem to use PHP but I would have thought nodejs would be more than enough for this? I don't have PHP on the box and would rather avoid it if I can stay in nodejs. Anyone got some pointers for me?

It might be worth noting that jquery is used but I don't know if that links in here? The following is at the foot of my html

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you edit the question and add the form inputs or elements you are using?

Answer (score 0):

I created solution for you:

```js
//connect express
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var ejs = require('ejs');
var partials = require('express-partials');
var app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(partials());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '../views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

//top level routing
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index.ejs')
});

app.post('/contact', function(req, res){
    res.render('thanks.ejs', {body: req.body})
});


//start server
var http = require('http');

var port = 3000;
app.set('port', port);

var server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(port);
```

```html
<!--- start index.ejs -->
<form action="/contact" method="post" class="form-signin">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Enter name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Enter email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Subject</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" placeholder="Enter subject">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Message</label>
    <textarea type="text" class="form-control" name="message" placeholder="Enter message"></textarea>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
<!--- end index.ejs -->

<!--- start thanks.ejs--->
<%=JSON.stringify(body)%>
<!--end thanks.ejs --->

<!--- start layout.ejs --->
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        <%-body -%>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<!--- end layout.ejs --->
```

My answer is based on this resource https://exceed-team.com/tech/form-submit-with-bootstrap-and-nodejs

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding the following to my `index.js`

```
    const bodyParser  = require('body-parser');
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
```

Now when I `console.log(req.body);` is get:

```
{
  name: 'name',
  email: 'name@x.y',
  subject: 'test',
  message: 'test'
}
```